# What is faster in terms of saving PC resources?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
if not ordero or not orderf:
```

OR

```
if(ordero=='' or orderf==''):
```

How can I test that?
I know that the right one is the first option.
But how to check that the first performance will work faster?

Answer (score 3):

For testing this type of string I normally a profiler.

> *A profile is a set of statistics that describes how often and for how long various parts of the program executed.*

[Python profiler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html)

It's not a solution to your exact problem but it can help you to make a decision on which function suits you better.

Hope it was useful!

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll try.

Answer (score 1):

there is no big difference:

```
import time

ordero = ''
orderf = ''

start = time.time()

for _ in range(10000):
    if not ordero or not orderf:
        pass

end = time.time()
print(end - start)

start = time.time()

for _ in range(10000):
    if (ordero=='' or orderf==''):
        pass

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Response on my system is:

```
$ python time.py
0.00140619277954
0.00133681297302
```

Comment: For me in 10 millions it was 0.6049275398254395 and 0.6864993572235107. Thanks.